# Verify parameter has same value for multiple expected calls in gmock

Tags: c++, googlemock

Given some mock function which takes at least one parameter:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(fun, void(int p));
```

How can i `EXPECT_CALL` two identical calls in terms of the value of parameter `p`? I don't care what the value of `p` actually is, as long as it is the same for both calls to the function `fun`. I have no way to predict the value of `p` in the test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option #1

```
EXPECT_CALL( mock, fun( testing::Truly( []( int p ) {
                 static int initial = p;
                 return initial == p;
             } ) ) )
    .Times( 2 );
```

#### Option #2

```
int p = 0;
testing::Sequence seq;
EXPECT_CALL( mock, fun( _ ) )
    .InSequence( seq )
    .WillOnce( testing::SaveArg< 0 >( &p ) );
EXPECT_CALL( mock, fun( testing::Eq( testing::ByRef( p ) ) ) )
    .Times( 1 )
    .InSequence( seq );
```